# C. The difference between realloc in double array and char array

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-management, realloc

I have to dynamically increase a length of double array. I know, how to do it with char array, so I tried this:

```
int main() {
    char * tmp = NULL;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        tmp = realloc(tmp, i * sizeof(char));
        tmp[i] = 'i';
    }
    puts("char OK");
    double * tmp1 = NULL;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        tmp1 = realloc(tmp1, i * sizeof(double));
        tmp1[i] = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The first array works fine. But the second one crushes with message `realloc(): invalid next size`.

These are my 2 questions:

1. Why this way doesn't work in a double array?
2. How to **dynamically** increase the size of array of doubles?

UPD:
removed a typo

Comment: What do you think `i * sizeof(double)` is when `i` is `0` and what happens then when you try `tmp1[i] = 0;`?

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. But anyway the error still occurs during realloc

Comment: Don't retype your code here but paste your _actual_ code.

Comment: @Yoskutik The effect is the same: if you allocated `i * <element size>`, `array[i]` does not exist and accessing it is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Both the snippets are wrong, the first one *appears* to work because of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To elaborate, the problem is with your indexing logic. C uses a 0-based indexing. So, inside the loop which is staring the iteration from value of `i` as `1`, by using

```
 tmp[i] = .......
```

you're trying to access invalid memory, at this point, only access up to `tmp[i-1]` is valid.

You need to use `tmp1[i-1] = 0;`, and likewise.

---

That said,

1. Always check for the success of the memory allocator functions before using the returned pointers.
2. Never use the form

   ```
     pointer = realloc (pointer, ......)
   ```

   because, in case `realloc` call fails, you'll end up losing the original pointer, too.

   Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.5

   > The `realloc` function returns a pointer to the new object (which may have the same
   >   value as a pointer to the old object), or a null pointer if the new object could not be
   >   allocated.

   and

   > [....] If memory for the new object cannot be
   >   allocated, the old object is not deallocated and its value is unchanged.

   - Always use a temporary pointer variable to store the return value of `realloc()`,
   - check for the success of the call [not-null return value] and
   - then assign it back to the original variable, if needed.